# Return array method, error

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I am trying to write a method that takes two arrays as parameter, and than return the sum of them. But I have two problems firstly I have error now that is saying incompatible types and is showing the error at return s. The other question is how to add 0 values to one array if it is shorter than the other.

Cheers.

```
public class Question1d{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        double[] v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        double[] w = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        double[] s;     
    }

    public static double add(double[] v, double[] w){
        int a;
        if (v.length >= w.length){
            a = v.length;
        }
        else{
            a = w.length;
        }
        double[] s = new double[a];
        for(int i = 0; i<=a; ++i){
            s[i] = v[i] + w[i];
        }
        return s;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is `s`? What is the return type of your method? What does the error message tell you (full message)?

Comment: Try the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) to start at the very beginning. I'd recommend downloading them to learn at your own pace. When you think you've mastered the basics, come back to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your method as returning `double` (a single value) not `double[]` (an array of values).

To handle the zero values work out the length of the shortest and the longest arrays.

Declare your results array to the longest length.

Loop through from 0 to shortest adding the values together.

Loop through from shortest to longest just copying the value from the longer array.

Comment: Firstly sorry if i am bothering u, but I am returning s. can you tell me more exactly where is the error

Comment: Your method signature says `public static double add(...)`. It needs to be `public static double[] add(...)` since the type of `s` is `double[]` not `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a `double[]`, not a `double` like you stated.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the updated code. you need to mention the return type as array in method.

```
public class Question1d{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        double[] v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        double[] w = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        double[] s;  
        for(double d:Question1d.add(v, w))
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    public static double[] add(double[] v, double[] w){
        int a;
        if (v.length >= w.length){
            a = v.length;
        }

        else{
            a = w.length;
        }
        double[] s = new double[a];
        for(int i = 0; i<a; ++i){

            s[i] = v[i] + w[i];
        }
        return s;
    } 
}
```

2.it is not possible to update the size of any array.